# WordPress - Subscriber Sign-on Ajax Notification

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, notifications

I stumbled across a little thought earlier today in regards to a community based website I am building within WordPress.

Before I ask, I have researched high and low across many different plug-in development communities to see if there is anything out there that could potentially deliver the functionality that I am looking for, but to no avail.

So, I thought I'd raise my question here - Always worth a shot to see what answers are brought to the table I guess!

Is it possible to have a frontend AJAX styled notification to appear (Almost similar to a Facebook notification) to indicate to other logged-in members that a member 'has just' signed in in to the website. E.g. "Brian has signed in".

That's as simple as my question is, but haven't found anything out there that really touches the surface in regards to the type of functionality I am looking for. Apologies if someone already knows of an existing plug-in that does this (I would be grateful for any pointers in terms of how/if this can be achieved)

Thanks!
Josh.

Comment: SignalR will help you achieve this.  When someone logs in it can push a notification to any/all other logged on users.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, will take a look in to this. Looks interesting, never stumbled across SignalR before.